# ¿Existe alguna api para poder mandar mensajes de whatsApp a traves de asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, whatsapp

Que tal, estoy por comenzar un proyecto y quisiera mandar un mensaje de whatsApp cada vez que haga un inserción de datos.

¿Existe alguna api para poder lograrlo?.

Comment: Lamentablemente, Whatsapp no permito el uso de software de terceros para que intervengan en la app. Si llegaras a lograr esto, es posible que seas baneado y nunca más puedas volver a usar WA.

Comment: Sólo hay un punto de entrada: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/90000011

Comment: como dice @Flxtr WA es muy estricto en el uso de bots, yo personalmente lo intente y fui baneado de distintos números. al final opte por la api de FB Messenger.

Comment: Estimado @Julio por ahora no hay una API oficial, te recomendaria ver [Bot Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/) que puedes desarrollar un solo codigo para varios "conectores" por ejemplo Telegram, Facebook Messenger, Slack, etc. Pero si tu requerimiento dice WhatApp deberias validarlo tecnicamente porque no es una API abierta